# QT creator can't open audio examples

Tags: qt4, demo, missing-data

**QT creator won't open multimedia examples.** When i try to open an example, i get a popup with the warning: "The project you are about to open is located in the write-protected location: /". I then have the choice of copying it to a directory or just opening it. If choose copy, it'll try to copy / to the chosen directory and fail halfway. Randomly picked non-multimedia examples all work.

After some further investigation, the entire /usr/lib/qt4/examples/multimedia/* directory appears to be nonexistent.

May somehow be related to [Why am I missing the Qt Multimedia functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410170)

*edit to make it more of a question:*
I'd like to be able to open the examples the usual way, via the examples gallery in QT creator. I'm new to multimedia programming, and want to try to make a simple and modern version of "virtual audio cable" to learn how it's done. I'll be opening and closing the examples a lot to un-clutter my workspace once in a while so **the question is**: 
how do i get the examples back where they belong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the examples online: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/examples-multimedia.html 
Still weird it's not included in the qt4-demos package while qtcreator expects it to be present (and consequently bugs out).